# Custom SVG Icons in IE 11 inside Lightning Component not rendering

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon, ie-11

I know this has been asked a lot and with revamped extended `IE 11` support for Lightning by Salesforce, the issue with SVG icons in `Lightning Component` arise again. I've been through the forum questions again and nothing seems to work in `IE 11` when it comes to a Custom SVG icons referenced from a Static Resource.

I have tried `svg4everybody`, even though I'm not sure if it works with `Locker Service` or not, but it has not generated the icons for me from SVG `<use>` tag href values.

I've a custom SVG icon file in a Static resource, and I use the custom SVG helper component to place my SVG icon in the markup.

**`svg.cmp` Lightning Component**:

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="class" type="String" description="CSS classname for the SVG element" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="xlinkHref" type="String" description="SLDS icon path. Ex: /assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#download" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="ariaHidden" type="String" default="true" description="aria-hidden true or false. defaults to true" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

**`svg.com Renderer`:**

```
({
    render: function(component, helper) {
        //grab attributes from the component markup
        var classname = component.get("v.class");
        var xlinkHref = component.get("v.xlinkHref");
        var ariaHidden = component.get("v.ariaHidden");

        //return an svg element w/ the attributes
        var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute('class', classname);
        svg.setAttribute('aria-hidden', ariaHidden);

        // Add an "href" attribute (using the "xlink" namespace)
        var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
        shape.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", xlinkHref);
        svg.appendChild(shape);
        return svg;
    }
})
```

Now, this helper Component injects `<svg>` into Lightning Component markup dynamically, and also injects `<use>` tag with path to svg icon. But it seems IE 11 does not support `<use>` tags.

Can anyone suggest how to rectify this issue?

I'm trying to call my custom SVG icon like this:

```
<c:svg class="slds-button__icon" xlinkHref="{!$Resource.custom_utility_icons + '/svg/media_logo.svg#logo1'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a known issue with IE 11 see similar issue and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516712/svg-use-tag-with-external-reference-in-ie-11) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868924/how-to-use-external-svg-elements-in-ie-9-10-11-use-tag).